# Given $(a_n)$ with $a_n \geq a_{n+1} \geq 0$ show that if $\sum \sqrt{a_n a_{n+1}} < \infty \implies \sum a_n < \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm having some difficulty solving this problem :

> Given the sequence $(a_n)$ with $a_n \geq a_{n+1} \geq 0$ show that if $$\sum \sqrt{a_n a_{n+1}} < \infty \implies \sum a_n < \infty.$$

I first thought of using the *Arithmetic Mean-Geometric Mean Inequality*:

$$\forall{a,b} > 0: \frac{a+b}{2} \geq \sqrt{ab}.$$

Therefore, since $a_n \geq a_{n+1} \geq 0$ we have: $$\frac{a_n+a_{n+1}}{2} \geq \sqrt{a_n a_{n+1}} \;\; \forall{n} \in \mathbb{N}.$$

but I can't use the *Direct Comparaison Test* here since it will only work to show the other side of the implication $\sum a_n < \infty \implies \sum \sqrt{a_n a_{n+1}} < \infty$.

Comment: $a_n \geq a_{n+1} \geq 0 \implies \sqrt{a_n a_{n+1}} \geq a_{n+1}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first term of the series is $a_0$ we have: $$\sum a_n - a_0 = \sum a_{n+1} = \sum \sqrt{a_{n+1}a_{n+1} } \le \sum \sqrt{ a_n a_{n+1} } < +\infty, $$
and thus $\sum a_n < + \infty$.

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n=a_1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sqrt{a_{n+1} a_{n+1}}<a_1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sqrt{a_n a_{n+1}}$$