# If $a_n$ monotonic, $a_n>0$, and $\sum\sqrt {a_na_{n+1}}$ converges, prove $\sum a_n$ converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series

need help solving this problem:

Given $a_n$ monotonic, $a_n>0$.

prove that if $\sum\sqrt {a_na_{n+1}}$ converges then $\sum a_n$ converges.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Also: am I right in assuming that "$a_n$ monotonics, $a_n > 0$ are *hypotheses* rather than conclusions to be proved? (if not, then the claim is false, as the constantly-zero series shows.)

Comment: You are right, I edited the question, thank you.

Comment: Also this
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1279707/if-sum-a-n2-converges-and-sum-b-n2-converges-does-sum-a-nb-n
and this 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1596014/let-a-n-and-b-n-be-two-sequences-of-real-numbers-such-that-series-a-n2-an

Comment: @PaulK, The links do not seem relevant to OP's question. The mechanism by which OP's sum $\sum a_n$ becomes convergent is quite different, and it is rather a partial converse.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, my bad

Comment: duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1561670

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

In the given convergent sum, use $\sqrt {a_{n+1}} \le \sqrt{ a_n}$ (in the useful direction of the inequality!).

[Edit: A sum of positive terms converges iff it is bounded. ]

Comment: I thought about it at first but I succeeded in proving that $\sum a_{n+1}$ converges and I am not sure if it aplies to $\sum a_n$.

Comment: One sum is $a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + \cdots$, while the other is $a_2 + a_3 + \cdots$ . The convergence of one implies the convergence of the other with the limits differing by $a_1$.

Comment: BTW, you should have stated what you weren't sure of in your original question! i.e., "showing work" helps people better answer your question.

Comment: You helped me a lot, thank you.